# Repeater multiselect selected item setting issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to check the multiselect item selected using c#, I'm getting the following exception:

> Error 29  Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its
>   string representation 'multiple' for the 'Multiple' property.

```
<select id="selProj" class="form-control" multiple="multiple"  runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="repProject" runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <option value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProjectId") %>">
             <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProjectName") %>
          </option>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
</select>
```

C# code is

```
var selectedProj = xElements.Element("SelectedProjects").Value.Split(',');

foreach (var pro in selectedProj)
{
    selProj.Items.FindByValue(pro).Selected = true;
}
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a different approach. Fill the select with the possible values during the post, then via javascript get the selected values and then select them up...

It's not what you expected but it's a bit better because:

1. you off-load your server
2. your page loads faster
3. your solution becomes more understandable by the whole community (remember that webforms is not only dying, but the whole java/ruby/php/etc part of the community does not get it very well, or at all)

Comment: _ASP.NET_ is not dying at all :) You may say that about **webforms** but not for ASP.NET!